# Basic application of the Nullstellensatz to locus of hypersurfaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. For $f \in k[x_1,...,x_n]$, write $V(f) \subset k^n$ for the hypersurface defined by $f=0$.

As an application of the NSS, I want to prove the following.

If $f$ is irreducible and $f$ does not divide $g$, then $V(f) \not\subset V(g)$.

My idea is to reason by contradiction and to suppose that $V(f) \subset V(g)$.

Now I consider the ideal generated by $f$. Since $f$ is irreducible, $(f)$ is prime and thus $(f) \neq k[x_1,...,x_n]$.

Since I supposed that $V(f) \subset V(g)$, the NSS (which I can apply since $k$ is algebraically closed) tells me that there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g^n \in (f)$. But this is a contradiction to the fact that $f$ does not divide $g$.

I am really unsure about my reasoning and my understanding of the NSS.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems reasonable to start with a contradiction, i.e., that $V(f)\subseteq V(g)$.  At this point, however, it may be better to observe that $I(V(f))\supseteq I(V(g))$.  You are essentially making such an observation, but the ideal $I(V(f))$ should be identified directly.

Now, the Nullstellensatz (and algebraic closure) comes in to show that $I(V(f))=\langle f\rangle$.  This requires the Nullstellensatz and algebraic closure since otherwise $V(f)$ might be empty, so $I(V(f))$ would be larger than $\langle f\rangle$.

Now, if $I(V(f))\supseteq I(V(g))$, then $g\in I(V(f))=\langle f\rangle$.  This, however, contradicts the fact that $f$ does not divide $g$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Dear Michael, I wondered if I could ask for some more help. I now want to deduce that if $g =$ const $\cdot \Pi f_i^{n_i}$, then the irreducible components of $V(g)$ are of the form $V(f_i)$. If I understand correctly, this follows from the counterpositive statement of what we showed above right?

Comment: @riri92 A follow-up question should be posed as a new question so that others also have a chance to answer.  To note: this new question is weaker than the original question as it doesn't require the Nullstellensatz or an algebraically closed field.

Comment: makes sense, sorry !